# Gzipping a File Using Zlib in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, zlib, cakefile

I'm trying to write a simple Cakefile build script for a small javascript library.  I'd like to gzip a source string and write the result to a file.  Here's what I have so far:

```
zlib.deflate minifiedjavaScriptSource, (error, buffer) ->
    fs.writeFileSync(javascript_destination_gzipped_minified_path, buffer)
```

When I run the script, it generated a `.gz` file as expected.  However, when I decompress this file, I get a `.cpgz` file.  If I try and decompress that, it just generates the original file again.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `gzip`, but are using `deflate` instead. :)

try `zlib.gzip ...`, that works fine:

```
% coffee
coffee> zlib = require('zlib'); 'ok'
'ok'
coffee> fs = require('fs'); 'ok'
'ok'
coffee> zlib.gzip('qweqweqweqwe', (_, buf) -> fs.writeFile('/tmp/test.gz', buf))
undefined

% zcat /tmp/test.gz
qweqweqweqwe
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is deflate supposed to do?

Comment: i dont know exactly, but deflate looks like another compression algorithm